# MySQL ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mysql, database, varchar, database-table

I have a MySQL table and I have the need of increasing the capacity of two columns. One column resized fine with this command:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY COLUMN COLUMN_NAME varchar(7000);
```

The other column returned the error message:

> ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Neither column is the Primary Key.

I am at a loss as to why one column would change in size without an issue while the other throws the error

Here is the table from the "DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME"; command:

```
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
|              | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| changed col  | varchar(7000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|              | varchar(1023) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|need to change| varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|              | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|              | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|              | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is my configuration from the SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'; command:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: You have an index  on the involved  column???? and which version of mysql you are using ???

Comment: If I did, would that be what is limiting the size?

Comment: "max key length is 1000 bytes"  ..is in the error message

Comment: I do have an index on the column. Is there a way to expand the size and keep the index?

Comment: In mysql there is  key length limit for index ..  which version of mysql you are using ?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: mysql 14.14   ... ????  .. not possible ..  could be 5.7

Comment: if you are  using innoDB (mysql db engine )  you can take a look at this ref  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-limits.html

Comment: mysql -V returned that line

Comment: Thank you that page is helpful

Answer (score 3):

Switch from ENGINE=MyISAM to InnoDB -- for a lot of reasons.  The relevant reason is that the limit is 3072, not 1000 in 5.7.

In general, it is not reasonable to index long string columns.

`VARCHAR(7000)` says truncate to 7000 characters.  You may as well simply declare it `TEXT`.  That has a limit of 64K bytes.  It, also, cannot be indexed.

In some rare situations, you can use a "prefix" index:  `INDEX(foo(99))`

For computing sizes "3 bytes per character" is used for utf8.

You may as well go all the way to utf8mb4.  (up to 4 bytes/char).

More on limits:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits